# Сериализация в Windows Phone 7.

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, visual-studio, serializable

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Пытаюсь сделать Serializable class, по привычке пишу:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace someNamespace
{
    [Serializable()]
    public sealed class SomeClass: ISerializable
    {
        private readonly long someField;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Однако под WinPhone7 это не работает, VS радостно заявляет, что не знает, что такое Serializable & ISerializable. Как это исправить? Приложение является портом с Java(Android), насколько помню Javовское "implements Serializable" это как раз C#-ское ":ISerializable". Не может такого быть, чтоб под winPhone не было такой возможности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что для Windows Phone нужно использовать вместо атрибута Serializable атрибут DataContract.

Кое-какие подробности:

[DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.95).aspx)

[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Сегодня попробую.

Comment: Ненавижу WP7 - вот именно из-за таких непоняток...

Comment: Похоже на правду. Только вот, чтоб проверить, надо полностью сделать портирование, хе-хе :p
Ну да ладно, принимаю ответ, должно работать.